# How to replace field in XML file using xmllint or xmlstarlet?

Tags: xml, bash, parsing, xmlstarlet, xmllint

I have the following xml file:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <aut:Session>
         <aut:IPAddress>127.0.0.1</aut:IPAddress>
         <aut:SessionToken>true</aut:SessionToken>
         <aut:ApplicationToken>861</aut:ApplicationToken>
      </aut:Session>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

What is the best way to replace `<aut:SessionToken>true</aut:SessionToken>` by
`<aut:SessionToken>false</aut:SessionToken>` ?

Here is what I'm trying:

```
xmllint --shell file.xml << EOF
cd //*[local-name() = "Header"]/*[local-name() = "Session"]/text()/*[local-name() = "SessionToken"]/text()
set failed
save
EOF
```

I'm having problems because of namespace when I try to replace true for false.

Br,
JD

Answer (score 2):

When dealing with a SOAP envelope I wouldn't use `*[local-name() = "…"]`
which ignores the namespace. Instead, use an explicit namespace binding.

To toggle the boolean, for example

```sh
xmlstarlet edit -N aut="http://" \
    --var T '//aut:Session/aut:SessionToken' \
    -u '$T' -x 'not($T)' file.xml
```

Add `-L` / `--inplace` before `-N` to edit the file in-place.

To read its value:

```sh
xmlstarlet select -N aut="http://" \
    -t -v '//aut:Session/aut:SessionToken' -n file.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there. You just have an extra `text()` element in there. In xmlstartlet, try

```
    xml ed -u '//*[local-name() = "Header"]/*[local-name() = "Session"] \
//*[local-name() = "SessionToken"]//text()' -v "false" yourfile.xml
```

Answer (score 1):

Your approach with `xmllint` is not far from correct. Just needs to add namespace handling and use namespace prefixes in XPath expression.

```
setrootns
cd //soapenv:Header/aut:Session/aut:SessionToken
set failed
save
```

As a one-liner:

```
echo -e "setrootns\n cd //soapenv:Header/aut:Session/aut:SessionToken\n set failed\n save\n bye" | xmllint --shell test.xml
```

Comment: This approach is much more readable instead `//*[local-name()…`. @LMC However, would you mind to explain the purpose of `setrootns`? Because it seems to be mandatory as it won't work without it?

Comment: `setrootns` makes the parser take into account namespaces declared in root element so prefixes can be used in xpath expressions. `local-name()` does not need namespaces at expenses of a more complex/hard to read expression. To take a look at `xmllint` shell commands run `xmllint --shell any.xml` and then issue a `help` command.

Answer (score 1):

### Howto: Debugging the XML structure and replacing values for a node

As Google might lead someone else here who has to alter his own XML file with a different structure and nodes, it could be arduous finding the proper syntax in order to change values.

*Sidenode*: eventough **xmlstarlet** might be the better tool for replacing values in XML files, most Unices have **xmllint** pre-installed.

Thus, the following practice shows how to navigate with **xmllint** in interactive mode (i. e. debug) through any xml file in order to find the *Node* (i.e syntax) which should be replaced.

```
xmllint --shell file.xml        # starts xmllint in interactive mode
setrootns                       # see LMCs explanation
cat                             # shows the complete XML structure

<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:aut="http://">
   <soapenv:Header>
      <aut:Session>
         <aut:IPAddress>127.0.0.1</aut:IPAddress>
         <aut:SessionToken>true</aut:SessionToken>
         <aut:ApplicationToken>861</aut:ApplicationToken>
      </aut:Session>
   </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body></soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Now you can walk step by step to the desired node through the XML tree :

```
cd //soapenv:Envelope                               # change to the first level
soapenv:Envelope >                                  # the prompt changes on success
cd //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session
aut:Session > cat                                   # appropriate prompt change

<aut:Session>
     <aut:IPAddress>127.0.0.1</aut:IPAddress>
     <aut:SessionToken>true</aut:SessionToken>
     <aut:ApplicationToken>861</aut:ApplicationToken>
</aut:Session>
```

Show directly the structure and values for a certain node/path (without prior `cd`):

```
cat //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session

<aut:Session>
     <aut:IPAddress>127.0.0.1</aut:IPAddress>
     <aut:SessionToken>true</aut:SessionToken>
     <aut:ApplicationToken>861</aut:ApplicationToken>
 </aut:Session>
```

Bear in mind to not have a trailing slash at the end of the path as it won't find the node:

```
cat //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session/    # trailing slash throws an error

XPath error : Invalid expression
//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session/
                                             ^
//soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session: no such node
```

Assuming we would like to change the IP address, its a good idea to check first the proper path:

```
cat //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session/aut:IPAddress

<aut:IPAddress>127.0.0.1</aut:IPAddress>
```

Or just get the value of the node:

```
cat //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session/aut:IPAddress/text()

127.0.0.1
```

Save first the original file as `backup.xml`, then apply changes to `file.xml`, save it and leave xmllint:

```
 cd //soapenv:Envelope/soapenv:Header/aut:Session/aut:IPAddress
 aut:IPAddress > cat text()         # alternative way to check the value
 127.0.0.1
 aut:IPAddress > save backup.xml    # create backup file
 aut:IPAddress > set 1.1.1.1        # change the value
 aut:IPAddress > cat text()         # crosscheck the changed value
 1.1.1.1
 aut:IPAddress > save               # save changes to file.xml
 aut:IPAddress > quit
```

In interactive mode `help` will show further details about commands. The section **#Shell** at [xmllint](https://gnome.pages.gitlab.gnome.org/libxml2/xmllint.html#shell) might also be a good resource.

As soon as the proper path for the node (which should be changed) has been identified, you can refer to the more efficient [one-liner](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71329801/7203861) as mentioned by @LMC to change XML files on the fly.